# How do I call the supercalss's function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, inheritance

I just started to learn Ruby. I have a question about how to refer to the superclass's method in the subclass if there is a method in the subclass that has the same name. In class B's method3(), I want to call method1 in class A,and not the local method. Is there a way I can call the method1 in class A instead of the method 1 in class B?

[image]

Comment: To add [code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), please use a code block.

Comment: Can you give an actual (real world) example where you would override a parent’s method but still want to call the original implementation? It’s doable, but I can hardly imagine a use case.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, you can't do it. You are doing an [overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) on the method, so you give to the parent's method a new implementation.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-method-overriding/) you can find some examples for Ruby.

So if you want to have two methods with a complete different implementation available for both Class (Parent and Child), you should use different names.

Comment: Well, the _"overriding"_ link you are referring to contains a [Ruby example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#Ruby) which shows how retain the super method via `alias`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really ever need this, there are two approaches I can think of:

###### 1. Save the original method

You can create an [`alias`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias) (or [`alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#alias_method-method)) before overriding `method1` and then call that alias just like a regular method:

```
class B < A
  alias orig_method1 method1

  def method1
    300
  end

  def method2
    400
  end

  def method3
    orig_method1
  end
end
```

###### 2. Dynamically retrieve the super method

You can call Ruby's [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-method) to get a *method object* for your method and then [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Method.html#call-method) its [`super_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Method.html#super_method-method):

```
class B < A
  def method1
    300
  end

  def method2
    400
  end

  def method3
    method(:method1).super_method.call
  end
end
```

---

Both of the above will result in:

```
B.new.method3
#=> 400
```

This is because `B#method3` calls `A#method1` which in turn calls the receiver's `method2`. (which is `B#method2` for instances of `B`)

Comment: `super_method` is new to me  I would have reached for `A.instance_method(:method1).bind(self).call` or `self.class.superclass....`